# Input Type="Date" Doesn't Recognize Date Returned from Rest

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date

I have a fetch that is getting about 12 SharePoint list column values. The one column value that I am having issues with is the column with the ID of "WeekOf" which is a date and time column.

The InfoPath form that users fill out that stores the items in the SharePoint list uses a "date" type input for the Week Of value, and that is stored in the form and the SharePoint list as MM/DD/YYYY.

When it is pulled through the fetch and stored in the network results tab of developer tools, it is then formatted as YYYY-MM-DDT05:00:00Z.

My application takes this SharePoint list data, and posts it to a HTML List on a printable page for records keeping. I have it so no data shows up on page load, and then users search for information based on the date that is associated with. When I set the input type to "date" and search for the appropriate date, nothing appears even if the date is the same. It seems like the input date is searching for a date with the format MM/DD/YYYY.

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Team": "Eagles",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31T05:00:00Z",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": null,
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Raiders",
      "WeekOf": "2021-01-31T05:00:00Z",
      "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Deliverables": null,
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    },
{
      "Team": "Vikings",
      "WeekOf": "2021-03-30T05:00:00Z",
      "Tasks": null,
      "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "NonBillable": null,
      "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
      "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
      "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
    }
  ];

function onSuccess(data) {
     var listContent = [];
   
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].Tasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Deliverables !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Actions !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Billable !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
         if(data[i].NonBillable !== null){
                 listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
         if(data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
         if(data[i].Training !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Resource !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].Support !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';         
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
   $('#under_txt').text(' ');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    onSuccess(data);
  });
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if($.trim(value)==''){
        onSuccess(data);
        return;
    }
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    $('[data-weekOf='+value+']').fadeIn();
  });
  
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
$('a.printPage').click(function(){
        $('#report-summary').show();
           window.print();
           return false;
});
```

```css
h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#search{
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center;
}
#under_txt{
margin-left: 5px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
@page { size:  auto; margin: 50px; }
@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
<div id="search">
<input id="myInput" type="date" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
</div>
<a class="printPage" href="#">Print Page</a>

<h1>
Weekly Report
</h1>
<p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
<div id="report-summary">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the load WORKS, please update your snippet to a [mcve] using an example object - your snippet is failing now

Comment: @mplungjan updating now. Give me one sec

Comment: We just want an example object and your loop

Comment: @mplungjan here is a fiddle, I will fix the snippet aswell https://jsfiddle.net/nmyd5h2b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes

1. data attributes must be lowercase
2. Your date picker is yyyy-mm-dd but your date attribute is yyyy-mm-ssThh:mm:ssZ

```
    $('[data-weekof]').each(function() {
      if (this.dataset.weekof.includes(value)) $(this).fadeIn();
    });
```

works if you lowercase the attribute

```js
var data = [{
    "Team": "Eagles",
    "WeekOf": "2021-01-31T05:00:00Z",
    "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": null,
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  },
  {
    "Team": "Raiders",
    "WeekOf": "2021-01-31T05:00:00Z",
    "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Deliverables": null,
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": null,
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  },
  {
    "Team": "Vikings",
    "WeekOf": "2021-03-30T05:00:00Z",
    "Tasks": null,
    "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": null,
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  }
];

function onSuccess(data) {
  var listContent = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    listContent += '<li data-weekof="' + data[i].WeekOf + '">';
    listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team + '</h2>';
    listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
    if (data[i].Tasks !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
    if (data[i].Deliverables !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
    if (data[i].Actions !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
    if (data[i].Billable !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
    if (data[i].NonBillable !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
    if (data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
    if (data[i].Training !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
    if (data[i].Resource !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
    if (data[i].Support !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '</li>';
  }
  $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
  $('#under_txt').text(' ');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  onSuccess(data);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(value, $('[data-weekOf=' + value + ']').length)
    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
      onSuccess(data);
      return;
    }
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    $('[data-weekof]').each(function() {
      if (this.dataset.weekof.includes(value)) $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });

});

function sortNewestFirst() {
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
}

function sortOldestFirst() {
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
$('a.printPage').click(function() {
  $('#report-summary').show();
  window.print();
  return false;
});
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#report-summary {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#search {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#myInput {
  text-align: center;
}

#under_txt {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 50px;
}

@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div id="search">
    <input id="myInput" type="date" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
  </div>
  <a class="printPage" href="#">Print Page</a>

  <h1>
    Weekly Report
  </h1>
  <p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
  <div id="report-summary">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your response to have no data show on load, but have the corresponding data to the date show up when searched then when changed, it is empty again? That is how I set it up now its a bit different